# iOS Reverse Geocoding and the Genre of the Place

Tags: ios

I have worked with iOS reverse geocoding but my question is that is it possible to find out that I have checked into a restaurant or a bank using reverse geocoding. I know reverse geocoding gives the street names and other stuff but does it tell exactly what type of place it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, reverse geocoding might tell you what *kind* of a location it is, such as "street", "ocean", "inland water" etc. But in order to get more semantics out of the location, you'd need to query other services, like foursquare or the like.

Comment: Maybe also Google Places API!

Comment: Sure, never tried it though. Just wanted to state that this has nothing to do with traditional "reverse geocoding".

Comment: Well with reverse geocoding and the Placemark classes I can find out the address of the place. I think if I send that address to a Google Places service then it might tell me that if that placemark is a restaurant or a hospital.